# How to unzip password protected .zip file using Terminal?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I need to unzip a `.zip` file which is password protected using `Terminal`

I am able to unzip the .zip file (if it is not password protected) using this command

```
unzip /Users/vikas/Desktop/as.zip -d /Users/vikas/Desktop/new\ folder
```

Note: I need to pass the **password** in the command. I know when it asks for the password, but my scenario is different as I have to pass the password in the command itself (e.g. `-p "my password"` in *Linux*).

Comment: `unzip` prompts for the password when needed.

Comment: I need to pass the password in the command. **Reason** is that I am working on an application that has a function to load data from zip file and I have to pass the whole command as one line

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the `-P password` argument to pass the password to `unzip`:

```
unzip -P password /Users/vikas/Desktop/as.zip -d /Users/vikas/Desktop/new\ folder
```

Comment: I keep getting a "Filename not matched"on the target dir

Comment: For me worked on ubuntu (20.04 focal) only "7z x <archive_name>" scheme to unzip password protected file made by (win10 winrar ZIP with pass). Only this asks me for password and not show error "unsupported compression method 99" or "ERROR : Wrong password". Even file manager or zip manager not worked and showed nothing after extraction.

Comment: supposed this is your password XlzFWqZL$0$s8w
You'll need to do something like this `unzip -P 'XlzFWqZL$0$s8w' yourfile.zip`

Without the quotation, you'll simply get "password incorrect" prompt back.

Answer (score 10):

In case of AES encryption unzip won't work. In such case 7z do the trick perfectly:

```
7z x <archive_name>
```

Comment: You can also enter the password on the command line instead of waiting for 7z to prompt for it, e.g. `7z x <archive_name> -pPASSWORD` - there's no space after the `-p`.

Answer (score 5):

you can use "[Unarchiver](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353?mt=12)" for it, works perfect.

Comment: Is unarchiver a terminal command? If it is an example would help, if it is not then it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime, `unzip` command doesn't work for me, so replace unzip with `ditto` will solve issue:

```
ditto -V -x -k --password --sequesterRsrc --rsrc FILENAME.ZIP DESTINATIONDIRECTORY
```